# Node.js app working with Server IP but not With Domain Name

Tags: nginx

Node.js app is running fine on port 80 (using PM2 and Nginx) and can browse through server IP well. But through domain it isn't working [This site can’t be reached]. On pinging the domain can see the server IP on the response.

Here is the Nginx config I used:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `server_name` declaration in your Nginx configuration.

```
server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html